# What's the best practice for Jenkins DIND in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am new to kuberenetes and recently created a kubernetes node , running jenkins-dind is a being a major problem. After some research I found out that mounting docker socket to the jenkins container is a major security issue and a bunch of articles saying kaniko is not good for security either.
What's the best practice to build docker images in the k8s cluster?

Comment: can you give some links saying 'mounting docker socket to the jenkins container is a major security issue', and i thought they would also give some solutions?

Comment: [Docker daemon attack surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) in Docker's security notes has some discussion.  In short, if you can run any `docker` command at all, you can `docker run -v/:/host -u root busybox vi /etc/shadow` and make arbitrary changes to the host system as root.